# minimum valid Cloud Job Ticket for Google Cloud Print privet createjob

Tags: google-cloud-print, google-cloud-print-privet

I'm writing a Google Cloud Print test and trying to add privet (local Google Cloud Print) functionality to it.
After a decent amount of futzing I've gotten /privet/printer/submitdoc   to print a page for my test but  /privet/printer/jobstate doesn't return status. Also it blocks for a while I tried using /privet/printer/createjob but the printer crashes. I'm not sure if the body I POST ed is a correct CJT ticket this is probably an error with the printer either way but I'd like to have a test I know should pass and I can't google any CJT examples.

Should this work?

{'version' : 1, 'print' : {'vendor_ticket_item': []}}

privet docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/privet

CJT docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd?hl=en#cjt

Answer (score 1):

Below CJT should work.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "print": {
    "vendor_ticket_item": [],
    "color": {"type": "STANDARD_MONOCHROME"},
    "copies": {"copies": 1}
  }
}
```

Thanks